# How to change MvvmLightLibs Dependency to the newest CommonServiceLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

In my project I use mvvm light package (v 5.3.0). Everything was OK until I updated package CommonServiceLocator to the new (2.0.1) version from version 1.3.0.
After this update, in code like this:

`ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);`

I get the following error:

> The type 'IServiceLocator' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.3.0

As my other packages also use CommonServiceLocator I prefer to get the latest versions.
How can I make the MvvmLight to use the new assembly?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the MvvmLight to use the new assembly?

You can't. It has a dependency upon the old version. You will either have to wait until a new version of `MvvmLight` that uses `CommonServiceLocator` 2.0.1 is released or revert back to using version 1.3.0 of `CommonServiceLocator`.

You can't "make" MvvmLight using a specific assembly or API without recompiling the library.